# How can I setup Cloud Composer to send email?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, smtp, sendgrid, google-cloud-composer

I want to get email notifications with [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer) but I am unsure how to do that. How can I configure a Composer environment to send email notifications?

Answer (score 6):

Because sending email or opening SMTP email relays can be a dangerous or prohibited Cloud behavior, we recommend you use [Sendgrid](http://www.sendgrid.com) to send email from Composer environments. The [Composer environment setup directions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating) contain a section specifically on [how to setup Sendgrid](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#notification) with Cloud Composer.

Comment: I tried to edit the answer but the queue is full - the link posted here does not have the Sendgrid instructions. Those are now linked from the writing DAGs page EmailOperator section https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags#emailoperator

Answer (score 0):

You can use **your own SMTP** (or even gmail) instead of Sendgrid.

Add your SMTP details to Cloud Composer as follows:

1. Configure email and smtp settings by overriding the email backend:
   https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/configure-email#configure_third-party_smtp_services  
    Because I was using SSL, I had to set:

```
    port=465
    smtp_ssl=True
    smtp_starttls=False
```

2. Add your smtp password to GCP Secret Manager:
   https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/configure-email#smtp_password 
   Additional note: don't forget to give your Cloud Composer service account access to the password by give it the role Secret Manager Secret Accessor in IAM.

Or **alternatively you can use Gmail**. 
I didn't try this myself, but I think it's good to know that this is also possible. 
Here's an example of someone describing the process:
https://helptechcommunity.wordpress.com/2020/04/04/airflow-email-configuration/